# Onsen UI sliding menu hyperlinks

Tags: cordova, onsen-ui

Just looked into Onsen UI. Looks excellent! One question though: in the *index.html* file I can modify the menu that links to the page displayed on the right. These links originally either point to *page1.html* or *page2.html*. However do they just change the name's title or actually load new pages? I have not been able to locate those pages, and they should be in the same directory since there is no indication to the contrary...

Can you help me understand how and where those pages are fetched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already addressed this on your last question, but I'll add the same answer here for convenience.

The page1.html (and page2.html, too) is actually inside the same index.html file. The

```
<ons-template id="page1.html">
<ons-page>
    .
    . Page content here 
    .
</ons-page>
```

is where it starts from. Can you find those?

What happens under the hood is that the Onsen UI compiles those ons-template tags to the real HTML, which is then injected to the DOM when needed, so for example the sliding menu popping up from left is actually the  element in your example app that you downloaded.

Comment: I was actually wondering for the same thing, when I first started with Onsen UI. Wasn't expecting those to be so near :)

Comment: You have two options. You can either put your pages in `ons-template` tags or you can have them in separate files. Onsen will first look if there's a template and then make a request.